# Swift 2.0, UITableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath returning nil for non-visible cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, ios9

Please don't mark this as a duplicate question because I have found no suitable answer for my query.

I have a table view with cells that contain text fields. I have a button at the bottom of the screen. The number of rows is greater than the screen can display, so some cells are not in view. I want that at any point when the button is pressed, all textfields be read and the text input be processed. I am unable to do so because apparently because of the reusability of cells, cells out of view do not exist at all and cellForRowAtIndexPath for those indexPaths gives a runtime error. I have read answers that say that this simply can't be done. But I find it hard to believe that there is no workaround to this. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely <strike>can't</strike> shouldn't be done (accessing cells that are off screen, or implementing workarounds to allow it), for reasons of (at least) performance and memory usage.

Having said that there is, as you put it, a workaround. What you will need to do it change how you are storing the values in those text fields. Rather than iterating through cells and retrieving the text directly from the text fields you should store the text for each field in an collection.

1. Define a dictionary property on your table view controller / data source to hold the text for each row.
2. Act as the delegate of `UITextField` and assign as such in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
3. Implement `textField:didEndEditing:` (or whatever is appropriate for your use case) and store the text in the dictionary keyed against the index path relating to the cell that contains that text field.
4. Update the button action method to use this dictionary instead of iterating through cells.

Comment: Hey Steve, I used your solution and it worked great! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a UITableViewCell subclass, add your tableViewCells a index property and introduce a delegate like:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
   func didEditTextField(test : String, atIndex : Int)  
}
```

Create a delegate variable on your UITableViewCell subclass.

```
var delegate : CustomCellDelegate?
```

Implement the UITextViewDelegate in your tableViewCell and set the cell to be the delegate of your textfield.

Implement these two methods:

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
  }

 func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField : UITextField) {
     // call back with the delegate here
     // delegate?.didEditTextField(textfield.text, atIndex: self.index)
 }
```

So when the user ends editing the textField, your cell will call out with a delegate, sending the text and the index.

On your viewController, when you init your tableViewCell, set the delegate of the cell to the viewController, and set the index to indexPath.row .

Set up on your viewController a String array with as many items as many tableViewCells you got. Init the array with empty strings.

So you got the delegate on your viewController, and whenever it is called, you just insert the returned text to right index in the string array on your viewcontroller.

What do think, will this work?

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that cells that have **NEVER** been created has no text inputs, then create an `Array` or `Set` ourselves and clone the content/input texts there whenever user inputs to a cell's textfield.

Whenever, that button is clicked, you can iterate the array instead of cells to get all the inputs.

This is a bit hacky though..